# ActiveRecord delete_all method updating instead of deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm using Rails polymorphic associations, that way some models have many `cash_histories` children, like this:

```
has_many :cash_histories, as: :cashable
```

But when I try to delete all cash histories from a parent `@resource`, like this:

```
@resource.cash_histories.delete_all
```

I get the following query:

```
UPDATE "cash_histories" SET "cashable_id" = NULL WHERE "cash_histories"."cashable_id" = $1 AND "cash_histories"."cashable_type" = $2  [["cashable_id", 1], ["cashable_type", "ServiceOrder"]]
```

I can't understand this behavior, setting relationship id to null instead of removing, that will result in dead rows in my table. Why is that happening?

I'm using Rails 4.1.

Comment: When trying to understand this behaviour, remember that you are sending the delete_all method to an *association*, not directly to a model.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From the Rails API docs for `delete_all`:

> Deletes all the records from the collection. For has_many associations, the deletion is done according to the strategy specified by the :dependent option. Returns an array with the deleted records.
>
> If no :dependent option is given, then it will follow the default strategy. **The default strategy is :nullify. This sets the foreign keys to NULL.** For, has_many :through, the default strategy is delete_all.

So you you just need to set the `:dependent` option on your `has_many` to either `:delete_all` or `:destroy`, depending on what behavior you want.

```
has_many :cash_histories, as: :cashable, dependent: :delete_all
```

From the Rails API docs for `has_many`:

> Objects will be in addition destroyed if they're associated with dependent: :destroy, and deleted if they're associated with dependent: :delete_all.

Comment: Where do you check Rails API? I looked at: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/delete_all before posting here and nothing says there.

Comment: @Jirico, http://api.rubyonrails.org/ -- But I pulled up a different docset... the one for ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-delete_all. It looks like Api Dock has that too if you look for it.

Answer (score 3):

its still weird because everywhere else it always describes what happens when the owner is destroyed.

> Controls what happens to associated objects when their owner is
> destroyed:
>
> :destroy causes the associated objects to also be destroyed.
>
> :delete_all causes the associated objects to be deleted directly from the database (callbacks are not executed).
>
> :nullify causes the foreign keys to be set to NULL (callbacks are not executed).
>
> :restrict_with_exception causes an exception to be raised if there are associated records.
>
> :restrict_with_error causes an error to be added to the owner if there are associated objects.

Comment: even the current documentation says "not honored"

delete_all(conditions = nil) public
Deletes the records matching conditions without instantiating the records first, and hence not calling the destroy method nor invoking callbacks. This is a single SQL DELETE statement that goes straight to the database, much more efficient than destroy_all. Be careful with relations though, in particular :dependent rules defined on associations are not honored. Returns the number of rows affected.